# IN clause makes query slower

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-10

I have a question about the performance tuning of `in` clause in sql query. The Postgres version is 10.18.

I did two queries below. The difference of performance of those two queries are huge. For sql, the only difference is the data in **where in**. One is `in('pool_1')`, another is `in('pool_1', 'pool_2')`.There are totally 6 million data in `table_1`. And there is actually no data whose `pool_id` is `pool_2`. I tried to use `join` instead of `in('pool_1','pool_2')`, but got the same bad performance.

Why the query with `in('pool_1', 'pool_2')` is so slow (3.4 seconds). Is there any way to improve it? By the way, I did `vacuum analyze` on both table_1 and table_2, but got the same analyze result. Thanks!

```
index: "index_1" UNIQUE, btree (pool_id, network, completed_at)
```

```
explain analyze SELECT *
        FROM table_a, table_b
        WHERE table_a.pool_id in ('pool_1','pool_2')
          AND table_a.network = 9
          AND table_a.del_id IS NOT NULL
          AND table_a.completed_at IS NOT NULL
          AND table_a.completed_at > '2000-07-30 05:59:33.40612' 
          AND table_a.dir_id = table_b.id order by table_a.completed_at limit 10;
```

```
------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=519937.20..519937.22 rows=10 width=724) (actual time=3446.229..3446.235 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=519937.20..521813.16 rows=750386 width=724) (actual time=3446.228..3446.231 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: table_a.completed_at
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 41kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=53283.89..503721.62 rows=750386 width=724) (actual time=199.493..2794.398 rows=908031 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (table_a.dir_id = table_b.id)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table_a  (cost=43921.17..402625.04 rows=750386 width=442) (actual time=143.916..717.730 rows=908031 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: ((pool_id = ANY ('{pool_1, pool_2}'::text[])) AND (network = 9) AND (completed_at IS NOT NULL) AND (completed_at > '2000-07-30 05:59:33.
40612'::timestamp without time zone))
                     Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1113808
                     Filter: (del_id IS NOT NULL)
                     Heap Blocks: exact=46519 lossy=66094
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_1  (cost=0.00..43733.57 rows=751764 width=0) (actual time=135.509..135.509 rows=908031 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((pool_id = ANY ('{pool_1,pool_2}'::text[])) AND (network = 9) AND (completed_at IS NOT NULL) AND (completed_at > '2022-07-30 05:59
:33.40612'::timestamp without time zone))
               ->  Hash  (cost=4990.32..4990.32 rows=86432 width=282) (actual time=55.262..55.262 rows=86394 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 16384  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 3468kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on table_b  (cost=0.00..4990.32 rows=86432 width=282) (actual time=0.012..14.404 rows=86394 loops=1)
 Planning time: 2.057 ms
 Execution time: 3447.105 ms
```

```
explain analyze SELECT *
  FROM table_a, table_b
  WHERE table_a.pool_id in ('pool_1')
    AND table_a.network = 9
    AND table_a.del_id IS NOT NULL
    AND table_a.completed_at IS NOT NULL
    AND table_a.completed_at > '2000-07-30 05:59:33.40612'
    AND table_a.dir_id = table_b.id order by table_a.completed_at limit 10;
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.97..24.58 rows=10 width=724) (actual time=0.066..0.102 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.97..1764475.78 rows=747598 width=724) (actual time=0.066..0.100 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using index_1 on table_a  (cost=0.56..1420987.03 rows=747598 width=442) (actual time=0.053..0.061 rows=10 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((pool_id = 'pool_1'::text) AND (network = 9) AND (completed_at IS NOT NULL) AND (completed_at > '2000-07-30 05:59:33.40612'::timestamp with
out time zone))
               Filter: (del_id IS NOT NULL)
         ->  Index Scan using table_b_pkey on table_b  (cost=0.42..0.46 rows=1 width=282) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=10)
               Index Cond: (id = table_a.dir_id)
 Planning time: 0.451 ms
 Execution time: 0.150 ms
(9 rows)
```

Comment: Two things you can try: a) rewrite the query as a UNION ALL of two subqueries (one for each pool) or b) add an index on `(network, completed_at, pool_id)`

Comment: Asking about the query performance you must provide complete CREATE TABLE for the data source, including all existing indices.

Answer (score 4):

After applying pool_id='pool_1' and network=9, the remaining part of the index is ordered by completed_at and the rows can be read in order and then it gets to step early once it catches its LIMIT.  (you can tell that by the lack of a Sort node in plan--The plan doesn't explicitly say "hey I'm using this index to provide order")

But after applying `pool_id in ('pool_1','pool_2') and network=9`, the remaining part of the index is in two disjoin pieces.  Each separate piece is ordered by completed_at, but the executor doesn't know how to stitch those separate pieces back together into an ordered whole on its own volition.

You can force it to do the correct thing by writing the query in a rather convoluted way:

```
(SELECT *
    FROM table_a
    WHERE table_a.pool_id = 'pool_1'
      AND table_a.network = 9
      AND table_a.del_id IS NOT NULL
      AND table_a.completed_at > '2000-07-30 05:59:33.40612' 
      order by table_a.completed_at) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
    FROM table_a
    WHERE table_a.pool_id = 'pool_2'
      AND table_a.network = 9
      AND table_a.del_id IS NOT NULL
      AND table_a.completed_at > '2000-07-30 05:59:33.40612' 
      order by table_a.completed_at 
 )
 order by completed_at
```

And then you would need to join this whole thing to the other table and apply the limit to it.  Since you didn't include create statements for the tables, I'm not going to try to figure out exactly how to do that part.